# CoffeeScript not passing variable

Tags: coffeescript

Folks,
  Trying to figure out the difference between these 2 statements, and why one works, and the other throws an error:

works:

```
jsonFileContents = fs.readFileSync('sample.json', 'utf8')
res.send(jsonFileContents)
```

does not:

```
jsonFileContents = fs.readFileSync('sample.json', 'utf8')
returnResult(jsonFileContents)

returnResult = (data) ->
    res.send data
```

error thrown:

```
`TypeError: undefined is not a function`
```

Comment: folks, i am fully aware of this function being synchronous :)  Just testing something here, and seeing this, thought i'd ask :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because returnResult is not defined upon usage.

The following should work:

```
returnResult = (data) ->
    res.send data

jsonFileContents = fs.readFileSync('sample.json', 'utf8')
returnResult(jsonFileContents)
```

Comment: So by placing returnResult above the call fixes this?

Comment: @Cmag Yes, because then returnResult is defined before you use it.